# Use local docker image without registry setup in k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've set up single node kubernetes  according to [official tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/).

In addition to official documentation I've set-up single node cluster:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Disabled eviction limit:

```
cat << EOF >> /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
evictionHard:
  imagefs.available: 1%
  memory.available: 100Mi
  nodefs.available: 1%
  nodefs.inodesFree: 1%
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

And set systemd driver for Docker:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

I've tried following:

```
docker build -t localhost:5000/my-image .
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Always --image=localhost:5000/my-image my-image
```

But in pod logs I see `ImagePullBackOff`. If I setup local repository and I do `docker push localhost:5000/my-image` after I build image, then everything is working.

Is it is possible to use local images (which are already available after issuing `docker images`) without needing to setting up local repository, pushing to this repository and then pulling from it?

Comment: the link you provided in the first line is about setting `kubectl` not a single-node cluster. please update, because it's now impossible to understand your setup and thus whether the node will have access to your local docker registry.

Answer (score 8):

You simply need to set the `imagePullPolicy` in your `Pod` template in the `container` specification to `Never`. Otherwise **the kubelet** will try to pull the image. The example `Pod` definition may look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: uses-local-image
      image: local-image-name
      imagePullPolicy: Never
```

More on that you can find [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#pre-pulled-images).

> By default, the kubelet will try to pull each image from the specified
>   registry. However, if the  `imagePullPolicy`  property of the
>   container is set to  `IfNotPresent`  or  `Never`, then a local image
>   is used (preferentially or exclusively, respectively).
>
> If you want to rely on pre-pulled images as a substitute for registry
>   authentication, you must ensure all nodes in the cluster have the same
>   pre-pulled images.
>
> This can be used to preload certain images for speed or as an
>   alternative to authenticating to a private registry.
>
> All pods will have read access to any pre-pulled images.

Answer (score 3):

mario's answer is correct. Would be complete with the command though. So, you want to create your deployment as follows:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart Always DEPLOYMENT_NAME --image my-image --image-pull-policy IfNotPresent COMMAND
```

Note: if you'd have more than one node, you would need to ensure on all of them you have an image with that name, as a repo doesn't exist, and it will fail.

Comment: Thanks @suren for your suggestion, I edited my answer by adding example `Pod` definition using declarative approach. It can be easily applied also to `Doployment`. Of course it can be done with imperative command as in your example. Only keep in mind that currently they are deprecated: `kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1beta1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl create instead.`