# how to pull docker images from localhost docker private registry to GKE?

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, docker-registry

I have my own docker private registry created in my host machine[**localhost**] and I intend to make use of localhost private registry to pull images in google Kubernetes engine.

How do I make it happen?

Comment: Please specify if you set up your **private docker registry** and pushed to it your recently build docker images or maybe you want you really want is rather using directly your locally built images which you can list with `docker images` command ? On **GKE** you typically use [GCR](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry) to which you need to push your locally built images before you can use them in your **GKE** cluster. And what do you exactly mean by `local` ? Is it a registry that you set up on your own computer ?

Comment: I have both setup in my localhost.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use either your *locally built docker images* (which can be listed by running `docker images` on your local machine) or *your locally set up **docker private registry*** (unless you make it available under some public IP which doesn't make much sense if it's your home computer). Those images can be used by your local **kubernetes cluster** but not by **GKE**.

In **GKE** we generally use [GCR (Google Container Registry)](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs) for storing images that are used by our **Kubernetes Engine**. We can build them directly from code (e.g. pulled from our github account) on a **cloudshell vm** (simply click **Cloud Shell** icon in your **GCP Console**). You can build them directly on this machine and you can push them to your **GCR** directly from there.

Alternatively, if you build your images locally, but by "locally" I mean this time the nodes where **kubernetes** is installed (so in case of GKE they need to be present on every worker node), you can also use them without a need of pulling them from any external registry. The only requirement is that they are available on all **kubernetes** worker nodes. You can force **kubernetes** to always use your local images, present on your nodes, instead of trying to pull them from a registry by specifying:

```
imagePullPolicy: Never
```

in your `Pod` or `Deployment` specification. More details on that you can find in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229606/11714114) answer.