# Kubernetes Deployment.yaml

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, npm

I have a docker image built and run with npm token how to convert this to deployment in Kubernetes. Below is my image and command to build and run.

```
#First Build
FROM node:16.17-bullseye

ARG NPM_TOKEN
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

#COPY package*.json .npmrc ./
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/
COPY .npmrc /usr/src/app/


RUN npm update
RUN npm install 

COPY . .


CMD ["npm","run","main"]
```

Buld command:

```
docker build . -t image --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=<token>
```

Run command:

```
docker run -p 3001:3001 -it -e NPM_TOKEN="Token" imageid
```

I'm using azure pipelines where image is build, pushed to azure container registry, then pulled and deployed to  aks (azure kubernetes service). Below is my deployment file :

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microa
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microa
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: microa
          image: acrURL/microa
          args: ["NPM_TOKEN=<token>"]
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "1500m"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3001
```

Comment: What have you tried? The normal way to do this is to write some deployment yaml and then apply it.

Comment: I should note that if you don't have a docker registry, you'll also need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228643/use-local-docker-image-without-registry-setup-in-k8s

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going in the right direction, one thing that needs to be corrected is that the "NPM_TOKEN" is written as an environment variable in your docker script, but in your YAML file, you defined it as an arg. So the correct deployment.yaml file would be:

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microa
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microa
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: microa
          image: acrURL/microa
          env:
          - name: NPM_TOKEN
            value: "<token>"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            limits:
              memory: "512Mi"
              cpu: "1500m"
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3001
```

Additionally, you have to port forward the container port to your localhost in order to access your application, the command below is equivalent to "-p 3001:3001" in your docker run command:

```
kubectl port-forward -n ingress-basic pods/microa 3001:3001
```

Once the port-forward is set up, you would be able to access your application at http://localhost:3001 .